# Fredholm transversality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, banach-manifold, hilbert-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be two Banach or Hilbert manifolds. Assume that $P\subset N$ is a smooth submanifold of $N$.
We say that a smooth map $f:M \to N$ is Fredholm transversal to $P$ if for every $x\in M$ with $f(x)\in P$ the pair$(Df_x(T_x M), T_{f(x)} P)$ would be a Fredholm pair.
(Recall that a [Fredholm pair in  a Banach or Hilbert space H](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-002-0473-z) is a pair of closed subspaces $(V,W)$ such that $V\cap W$ is a finite dimensional space and $V+W$ is a closed subspace of $H$ with finite codimension.

> Is this terminology introduced in some reference?
>   Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Is there a submanifold $P\subset H$ for which there is no a surjective map $f:H \to H$ such that $f$ is Fredholm transverse to $P$? In particular does the unit sphere $P$ of $H$ admit a surjective Fredholm transversal map?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the definition of the pair.

Comment: @ThomasRot  I think it is identical to what the libked paper originally wrote.

Comment: Quote from the paper:"We recall that a Fredholm pair is a pair of closed subspaces (V,W) such
that V +W is closed and finite codimensional, V ∩W is finite dimensional"

Comment: @ThomasRot Why do you think that there is a typo?

Comment: Shouldn't $(Df_x(T_x M), T_{f(x)} N)$ be $(Df_x(T_x M), T_{f(x)} P)$?

Comment: Otherwise the condition is that Df has finite rank

Comment: @ThomasRot  Ah yes yes. I am sorry. I revise it. Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: You might be interested in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309020.pdf

Comment: @ThomasRot I realy thank you very much for this  very instructive and interesting paper.